# How to lazy load react component on scroll(Virtual/Infinite scrolling)?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll, lazy-initialization, intersection-observer

Usually in high traffic application like e-commerce need to ensure about page load size and TTI.
Scenario, When user visiting the page, we just need to load all the components only in the viewport. if we render everything at the page load will cause the TTI/Performance issue.
**How to implement this in react without much logic or config or listeners?**

Comment: Library to lazyload - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-observer-api